# when i debug my programer,it shows program receive a signal SIGSEGV,segmentation fault

Tags: c

this is the wrong code,while i transfer it in my main code , it shows program receive a signal SIGSEGV,segmentation fault.whats wrong with it?

```
char *DeleteList(LinkList L,char* e,int i)
{
    LinkList p;
    p=(LinkList)malloc(sizeof(LNode));
    p=GetNode(L,i-1);
    *e=p->next->data;
    p->next=p->next->next;
    free(p);

    return e;
}
```

the main function

```
int main()
{
    char *e;
    LinkList L,p,z,q;
    L=CreatListH();
    p=(LinkList)malloc(sizeof(LNode));
    e=DeleteList(L,e,3);
    p=L;
    p=p->next;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%c",p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }
```

the head File statement

```
#define ERROR 0
#define OK 1

typedef struct LNode{
    char data;
    struct LNode *next;
}LNode,*LinkList;

LinkList CreatListH();
LinkList CreatListT();
LinkList GetNode(LinkList L,int i);
LinkList LocateNode(LinkList L,char e);
int InsertList(LinkList L,char e,int i);
char *DeleteList(LinkList L,char* e,int i);
int ListLength(LinkList L);
void DifferenceList(LinkList La,LinkList Lb);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your program is incomplete and cannot be compiled.

Comment: And what does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but: Return value from `malloc` doesn't need to be cast. And hiding pointers in typedef is not a good idea.

Comment: `p=(LinkList)malloc` is a memory leak as you throw away the address in the next line

Comment: Just a guess: `*e=p->next->data;` this is UB as `e` is not initialized.

Comment: @Gerhardh,thank you ,you are right

Comment: `p=(LinkList)malloc(sizeof(LNode)); p=anything;` isn't a great idea. It's like doing `int n=1; n=2;` then wondering why `n` isn't 1.

Comment: `valgrind` can help you diagnose pointer issues